# assign :_id via route.js to use it in template.js - Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have 2 Collections:

Collection 1:
`Categories`

Collection 2:
`Posts` - with `category_id` so a `Category` have some `Posts` with the same `category_id`.

I have a template where I can see all my categories and I want now to click on a category to see its  Posts where `category_id` is `:_id`.

route.js:

```
    this.route('postsList', {
    path: '/category/:_id',
    data: function() {
        return myCategories.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
```

now I know which category I have chosen but I have no clue how to get the _id in my template.js to do something like:

```
    Template.postsList.helpers({
        drinks: function(){
            return Posts.find({id:_id});
        }
});
```

The Problem is that I would like to get the :_id from my route into my template.js to work with it. `this.params._id` is not working for me in my template.js.

Comment: If you're setting the data context in `postList` to the category in question, then `this._id` should give you its `_id` in your helper function, *unless* you've overwritten the context somewhere (in which case it'll be more complicated).  But you probably just need `this._id`, or `Template.currentData()._id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the category id to your helper from html template.

You will need to pass the `_id` from your html  to your helper function `drinks`

Something like this-

`{{drinks _id}}`

instead of just

`{{drinks}}`

Now, in helper get the `id` as parameter

```
drinks: function(id){
  // here you have the id passed from html, do whatever you want

}
```

Hope this helps.